# What is the standard way in delphi 5 to watch for a selection change in a DBGrid?

Tags: delphi, selection, delphi-5, dbgrid

I have many "master/detail" forms in my application. A TDBGrid where each row shows a few core values of the item. Below the grid is usually a "Detail area" that shows the complete information of the item that is currently selected in the grid.

Currently I am listening to the "AfterScroll"-event of the TADOQuery behind the grid, but it seems to give me too many events.

Is AfterScroll the correct event for this? How are you doing this?

Answer (score 4):

The "standard" way (in a data-aware environment) would be to not control that using GUI controls, but rather using the data components.

Most of the table data sets provide `MasterSource` (linked to an appropriate `TDataSource` component), and `MasterFields` properties.
You use these to link your datasets in a master-detail relationship.
Then your detail grid *(or other data-aware controls)* only needs to concern itself with linking to the correct dataset.

**EDIT**
Other kinds of datasets (e.g. `TQuery`, `TADOQuery`) sometimes provide `DataSource` to be used for a similar purpose. From Delphi 5 help: "`Set DataSource to automatically fill parameters in a query with fields values from another dataset.`"
However, there are quite a few more complications (as will be observed reading the help). So it may be advisable to use `TTable` or `TADOTable` for the detail dataset instead.

Comment: I'm using delphi5, and I don't see a MasterSource property, just DataSource. Is that a newer feature?

Comment: MasterSource and DataSource are not the same. But because differences depend on the particular component you're using, I'm going to refer you to the help files. - And of course just experiment! :) MasterSource also isn't available on all dataset controls (You probably checked TQuery). In Delphi 5 (according to Help file) it's on TADOTable, TClientDataSet, TIBTable, TTable. (As indicated in my answer - the **table** data sets.)

Comment: @Zalumon PS: You could try DataSource on TQuery, but there will be a few more things to watch out for. Again, refer to help files. ;)

Comment: hm, I believe I do not understand at all what you're trying to tell me. Currently I am listening to the "AfterScroll"-event of a TADOQuery (I don't see how I could use a table here). TADOQuery is not a GUI control, or what do you mean? Also I do not have a detail grid, but a rather a whole area with many components that I manually update when the event fires.

Comment: @Zalumon I missed that you're not using a detail grid (because usually master-detail relationships are 1-to-many). However, that doesn't change anything. If you're following a data-aware approach, then the detail controls should still link to the detail dataset. However, if your detail controls are not data-aware, then you're mixing paradigms, and I strongly advise against this. (I've updated my answer to mention using DataSource on TQuery or TADOQuery.)

Comment: say I need to build custom data series for a chart, or generate a custom image, or build a custom SQL query, or generate a complex report, all based on the selection in the main table grid. I believe what I am doing is pretty standard. In Java for example I would listen to some kind of selection change event of some selection model.

Comment: Granted. If your detail data is not accessible from a dataset, then you have to mix the paradigms. In that case `AfterScroll` can be used. You can avoid repeated event triggers by checking if the key values of your master are actually different (obviously this is a little messy). However, if your master grid is editable, then simply hooking `AfterScroll` might be insufficient. In that case, you may want to use `TMasterDataLink` standalone. (This is what TTable uses internally for its master-detail relationships.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware if there's any 'standard' way but IMO `AfterScroll` is fine. Use a timer to prevent updating controls in quick succession, for instance while scrolling the grid. An example:

```
procedure TSomeForm.DataSetAfterScroll(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  if not DataSet.ControlsDisabled then begin
    if ScrollTimer.Enabled then
      ScrollTimer.Enabled := False;
    ScrollTimer.Enabled := True;
  end;
end;

procedure TSomeForm.ScrollTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ScrollTimer.Enabled := False;
  UpdateGUI;
end;
```

I think you'll find an interval of 250-300 ms pleasant.